# SQL: Finding/Deleting entries for each member based on timestamp difference

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a MySQL table of actions with the following key fields (all of them are integers):

```
Actions
id | member_id | timestamp (seconds)
```

This table keeps all the actions that every member does.

**My problem:**  there are entries that were inserted by error. I need to find (eventually delete) all actions per member where the timestamp difference is less than 1 day (86400 seconds)

So for example, taking the following 4 actions for one member:

```
id | member_id | timestamp  | (difference)
---|-----------|------------|----------
1  |     1     | 1499500834 | 
2  |     1     | 1499580834 | 80000 (22 hours)
3  |     1     | 1499640834 | 60000 (16 hours)
4  |     1     | 1499700834 | 60000 (16 hours)
```

I would need to determine that:

- the 1st is valid (because it's the 1st action registered)
- the 2nd is invalid (< 24 hours compared to last valid: 1st)
- the 3rd is valid (> 24 hours compared to last valid: 1st)
- the 4th is invalid (< 24 hours compared to last valid: 3rd)

And thus delete the 2nd and 4th.

How would I go about this in SQL ?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Column timestamp's data type?

Comment: Why 1st is valid and 2nd not? What if 1 and 3 are invalid and 2 and 4 are? That would still fall under the rule that 24 hours must pass between activities...

Comment: I think you're going to struggle in SQL, due to the recursive nature of your problem.  if you have another programming language available it may be easier.

Comment: As already stated you might need to solve this with something other than SQL. On which environment are you working (Windows/Linux/..) ?

Comment: @jav I'm working with php, on a Temma framework. I think I'll be fine if I do it in php, I'll post the answer when I do it. Thanks!